# Floor functions in a set of numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Find the number of distinct numbers in the list
$$\left\lfloor \frac{1^2}{1000} \right\rfloor, \ \left\lfloor \frac{2^2}{1000} \right\rfloor, \ \left\lfloor \frac{3^2}{1000} \right\rfloor, \ \dots, \ \left\lfloor \frac{1000^2}{1000} \right\rfloor.$$

The floor of all numbers till $\left\lfloor\frac{32^2}{1000}\right\rfloor$ are all $0.$ Assuming this goes in cycles of $32,$ there will be $31$ cycles of the $32,$ making there $\boxed{31}$ distinct numbers in this list. Is this the right track?

Comment: Note that the final fraction is $1000$, and three penultimate expression becomes $998$, so the pattern can't be that simple.

Comment: The cycles will get shorter as you go up.

Comment: hmm, oh right. How would I start this problem?

Comment: It might help to great it up into 2 parts: where the difference between consecutive terms (ignoring the greatest integer function) is less than 1, and where it is greater than 1.

Comment: Wouldn't it take a long time to find out all of the places with that difference? Could you elaborate a little more? Thank you, :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\lfloor \frac{x^2}{1000} \rfloor = k$ for some integer $k$. This means:

$$k\leq \frac{x^2}{1000}<k+1$$

$$1000k\leq x^2 \leq 1000k+999$$

It is clear that when $x\geq 500$, $(x+1)^2-x^2=2x+1>1000$ so each value of $\lfloor\frac{x^2}{1000}\rfloor$ is distinct. That's $\fbox{501}$ distinct values from $x=500,501,\cdots,1000$

For $x < 500$ i.e. $k < 250$, all $k$ can be satisfied. $k$ ranges from $0$ to $249$ here, so $\fbox{250}$ distinct values here.

Therefore the answer is $250+501=751$.

Comment: Note that the "i.e. $k<250$" comes from $1000k \leq x^2 < 500^2$

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Let me read your explanation!

Comment: Also I am not sure about some specific floor/rounding issues, but approximately if you replace $1000$ with $d$, the answer will be approximately $\frac{3d}{4}$.

Comment: 750 values seems like quite a lot. Since it is the floor of each of the values, I'm not sure if  it this big.

Comment: @StarLight Check yourself here: https://tio.run/##bY07DoMwEAVr@xSvtBEfm3SRyEUiCqRA2GZZ2TQ@vXEkUiDRzszTk7SvGz8aSZJyjhjwHvWyBRCIESb@zsbX8M55@9SKliKqCj267gcdXjCEBt5ecEmVBOId5k7XiLYU552K7SQy88eQ1efqX@V8AA In particular, think of it as grouping square numbers into buckets of 1000s. For multiple squares to be in the same bucket, they must be within 1000 with each other. In fact really quickly, $(x+a)^2-x^2=2ax+a^2\leq 1000$ has few solutions for $a>1$.

Comment: Alright :D; Thanks again!

Comment: You missed the case for $k=500$. The answer should be $751$.

Comment: ah yes fxck oops